# Authentication via NTLM and Feign Client in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ntlm, spring-cloud-feign

I am trying to use Feign Client to do authentication via NTLM.

Unfortunately, I have an error:

*feign.FeignException $ Unauthorized: [401 Unauthorized] during [GET] to [url]*

```
@FeignClient(name = "ntmlClient", url = "url", configuration = FeignClientConfiguration.class)
public interface NtmlClient {

@GetMapping(consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
ResponseEntity<Aup> get();
}


@Configuration
public class FeignClientConfiguration {


@Bean
public BasicAuthRequestInterceptor basicAuthRequestInterceptor() {
    return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor("admin", "admin");
}
```

Any hints?
Can Feign Client be used for NTLM authentication?